# Class hierarchy of NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

I trying to understand class hierarchy. What are the sub classes of `NSObject`. Is there any graphical representation of the hierarchy?

Comment: The set of potential `NSObject` subclasses is not finite - you can add custom ones as much as you want. Are you asking for a diagram for the Cocoa Touch classes?

Answer (score 2):

You can explore the hierarchy in the hierarchical view of the Symbols navigator in a Xcode project. Be sure to de-select the document icon below to display all symbols and not just those defined in your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The class browser under `Project>Class Browser`will display a hierarchal view of all the classes. There are a lot of them.

Comment: Where do u find this Project>Class Browser ? Can u please show the exact path where we can check the hierarchy of the classes?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a diagram explaining about NSObject class references but its not the one. There are so many things to know about NSObject. On the other hand its not finite, means you can add your custom classes also.

[image: iOS NSObject class reference]

Hope this helped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Xcode

```
Show the Navigator -> Show  the Symbol Navigator
//or 
Command + 3

Hierarchical -> Classes -> NSObject
```

[image]

You can use `Filter` field or `Navigate -> Reveal in Symbol Navigator`. Sometimes `Filter` field is buggy that is why you should repeat actions

Answer (score 0):

**NSObject** is the **root class** of most **Objective-C class hierarchies**, from which subclasses inherit a basic interface to the runtime system and the ability to behave as Objective-C objects.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject

I found this [this](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://iosdevelopmenttutorials.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/uikit_classes.jpg&imgrefurl=https://iosdevelopmenttutorials.wordpress.com/tag/class-hierarchy/&tbnid=g2M5r6yl_DDrWM&vet=1&docid=S4vmpvzktSfl7M&w=873&h=1159&source=sh/x/im) diagram on Google showing the inheritance relationships.

A comprehensive blog is written by **Chris** (**Just read **Chapter#12****):

https://codewithchris.com/swift-tutorial-complete/#uikit
[Chapter 12](https://document.getElementsByClassName(%22chaptersubheading%22)%5B12%5D;)